# Canvas to Image in javascript?

Tags: javascript, image, canvas, html5-canvas

I'm trying to transform a canvas on html image.

The canvas is display without any problem, in  $('#image1') there are some data, but it's not display ? What i have forget ?

Here is a jsfidle with the code : http://jsfiddle.net/mcbjam/tZGcq/

Here is the call i need to perform.

```
$('#image1').attr('src', image.src);
```

Comment: You forgot to set up a live demo: http://jsfiddle.net

Comment: @icktoofay I'm assuming that OP wanted to include a live demo, but forgot. (I'm an optimist `:-)`.)

Comment: Here is a live demo. Maybe it will work at the end of the question :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're drawing an image from another domain. When you do this, the canvas becomes *tainted*, and you can't get at the data any more because that might reveal data from that other domain that you normally wouldn't be able to access.

You can fix this by copying the image file to your own domain and then using a relative URL to access it.

---

Additionally, you'll probably want to call `convertCanvasToImage` from inside the `img.onload` callback, but that's not your primary problem.

Comment: The fix is to have a simple script on your server to act as a proxy. Something as simple as `<?php readfile($_GET['filename']); ?>` accessed by `proxy.php?filename=http://images/aviary.com/imagesv5/feather_default.jpg`

Comment: @Kolink: I'd hope it wouldn't be *that* simple: `proxy.php?filename=/etc/passwd`

Comment: Does there any way to do so without having to upload the image on my domain ?

Comment: @icktoofay True XD McbJam: You can use my script, but make sure you add some validation in there, such as making sure the file starts with `http://`

Comment: Thanks @icktoofay  but you forgot the script :) or bas paste/copy.

Comment: @McbJam: I didn't write the script, Kolink did. Look at the first comment on my answer.

Comment: If I do some transformation on the canvas ? It would not convert the data on local data ?

Comment: I'm on google app engine in java. So i can not perform a proxy without url rewrite, or i have to upload the file. Are there any way to do the transformation locally ?

Comment: @McbJam: If by locally you mean client-side, no. It is intentional that you cannot access data from other domains.

Comment: One more questions please. If the image is serv by another domain but i put document.domain="maindomain", will this do the trick ?

Comment: @McbJam: I'm not all that familiar with `document.domain` but I'm pretty sure that won't work, but by all means go ahead and try.